# Text getting out of div container

Tags: html, css

This is what i want -
1. div should have min height 100% so that it border shows full screen
2. it should be in horizontally middle. 
3. it should be stretch with the content inside.

Now problem is these all 3 things are working but in last "hello" is getting out of container. i have used clear float. but its not working. 
help me out with some css trick. or point out if i'm doing something wrong.

Here is jsfiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/2U5hh/

this is my html code-

```
<body>
  <table class="clearfix">
   <tr height="15%">
    <td id="image_td">
      <img src="img/smthing.png" alt="E-Learn" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="85%">
    <td>
      <div id="td_content_div">                        
        <p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p>
        <p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p>
        <p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p>
        <p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p><p>hello</p>
      </div>
     </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
```

And here is css code-

```
html, body
{
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0 0 0 0;
} 

.clearfix {
max-width: 500px;
margin: 2% auto;
border-radius:25px;
padding:2% 2% 5% 2%;
height:96%;
width:96%;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(83, 39, 134, 1);
}



#image_td{
float: right;
margin-right: 5%;
margin-top: 2%;
}

#image_td  img{
max-width:96%;
height:auto;
}

#td_content_div {
position:relative;
border-radius:25px;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(83, 39, 134, 1);
width:94%;
height: 94%;
 margin:3% 3% 1% 3%;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Something like this do you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Pzz22/

Comment: yes i want text inside. but it gets outside as we put some more "p" tag inside.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Pzz22/2/ And this?

Comment: It is good. but i dont want it too be scrollable, i just want it to get stretched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but if you just want the last p to stay in the container, all I did was change the height of #td_content_div to 100% and it seemed to work. You might be able to entirely remove the height declaration on that id, but it doesn't seem to respect the paragraph's margins then. That could be the desired effect depending on the situation.

Comment: your solution worked.i did set height to 100%  Now this is what i wanted. http://jsfiddle.net/Pzz22/6/   http://jsfiddle.net/Pzz22/7/  Its working fine now.thnx

Answer (score 0):

Add `height:auto;` to `#td_content_div`

Comment: This is what happen when i use auto.http://jsfiddle.net/Pzz22/4/ i want that container get full screen height.

Answer (score 0):

```
#td_content_div {
position:relative;
border-radius:25px;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(83, 39, 134, 1);
width:94%;
height: 94%;
margin:3% 3% 1% 3%;
vertical-align: middle;
height:auto;
}

p { margin-left:20px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pzz22/3/

Comment: This is what happen when i use auto. jsfiddle.net/Pzz22/4 i want that container get full screen height.

Comment: Yes but you set it with fixed pixels, i dont want that cause i'm making my page responsive. thnx for help. and it is already solved. i changed #td_content_div to 100%. now its not getting out of container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put **height:auto** and **overflow:auto** like this:

```
#td_content_div {
position:relative;
border-radius:25px;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(83, 39, 134, 1);
width:94%;
 margin:3% 3% 1% 3%;
vertical-align: middle;

height: auto;
overflow:auto
}
```

In case you will set only height:auto, there will be some ugly content over rounded corner. Cheers!